# Entity framework does not return null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting a bit confused here. If my query does not return anything why isnt coupon null? And how should I check for null?

```
Coupon coupon;

using (var db = new KupongEntities())
{
    coupon = (from p in db.Coupon
        where p.CouponID == 123
        select p).SingleOrDefault();
}

if (coupon != null)
{
    //test
}
```

Comment: You're using SingleOrDefault, so it'll return an instance of Coupon, or null if nothing was found in your collection.

Comment: it will actually return default(Coupon) which 'may' be a new coupon, you can redefine default on your objects

Answer (score 0):

> If my query does not return anything why isnt coupon null?

Your question is a touch confusing. Are you saying that you are executing that query and not getting a `null` value despite you think that there shouldn't be a result? Then one of three things is happening:

1. You're wrong that there is no result.
2. You're right that there is no result, but wrong that the returned valued is not `null`.
3. `Coupon` is a struct.

I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that 1. and 2. are not the case. In the last case, `coupon` will receive the default value for an instance of `Coupon`. The default value for a struct is that which has all of the fields of the struct set to their default value. In this case, you should say

```
if(coupon != default(Coupon)) {
}
```

But then you have the nasty problem where the default instance of `Coupon` might be a valid entry in your database anyway. I'd reconsider making `Coupon` a struct if I were you.

> And how should I check for null?

Well, if `Coupon` is a reference type, exactly what you have is fine. If `Coupon` is a struct, you'd check as it as I've shown above.